# Parsing Fanart API v3 with python3

Tags: python, json, parsing

forgive me, if if come straight out with it but python drives me nuts at something what seemed to be quite simple.

In a nutshell
I'm writing an extension for a musicvideo **scraper** which is responsible for getting the fanart backdrop.
Here is the URL:
[github.com/MViDLibraryToolKit/.../APICaller](https://github.com/sKiLLeSS1986/MViDLibraryToolKit/blob/master/python/APICaller.py)

So I was able to call the Fanart.tv API and receiving the right json response. My problem is that i'm to dumb to collect the URLs under the Element "artistbackground"

I search the internet and found a very similar post here at stackoverflow but unluckily this was concerning python2,API V2 and a different category at fanart.tv so I was not able to take use out of it. [Here it was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914545/get-corresponding-value-from-json-key-in-python)

Anyway, here is my poor Try to collect URLs to list

```
# --------------------- Response Verarbeitung

# Ausgabe zwecks Debug
# print(fanartTVresp)
# http://webservice.fanart.tv/v3/music/albums/ba853904-ae25-4ebb-89d6-c44cfbd71bd2?api_key=fdadba00cfaaf3621eaa748669256a9e&client_key=dce01d75553d7e3fbc2ad742aaf5d371

# zu befüllende Liste
url_list = []

# lade Web-Response
json_response = json.loads(fanartTVresp)

# durch Element artistbackground loopen

for artistbackground in json_response:
    url = urllib.parse.quote(['url'], ':/')
    if url:
        url_list.append(url)
print(url_list)
```

The libs I loaded...

```
import musicbrainzngs
import urllib
import json
import socket
from pprint import pprint
from urllib.parse import quote
```

The rest from the code you can find at my github link. Please help me, it drives me crazy ^^

Kind regards

p.s. Please excuse my english, I came from germany :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it.

```
# URL List for background images
url_list = []

# set only for debug / value came from  powershell runtime later
location = os.path.abspath('C:/temp')


# decode json
json_response = json.loads(fanartTVresp.decode())

# set string objects

bgitem = json_response["artistbackground"]

bgcoverurl = json_response["artistbackground"][0]["url"]

# iterating items and collect
for bgcoverurl in bgitem:
    url_list.append(bgcoverurl)
    print(url_list)
```

After taking some hourse of sleep I reallized that "json.loads" deserialized the response to regular python objects. Correct me if I'm wrong.
Anyway, it finally works!